# Express redis session not working locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, session, redis

My redis session isn't working locally.

EDIT:

Also just found out it actually doesn't save a cookie

setting req.session[somekey] is undefined
like:

```
req.session.user = user;
```

BUT

when working with Postman - it works - Postman to my localhost api endpoint

I've got a session key - same functions, same processes

which means its something environmental - and I'm not sure what...

code blow

session middleware

```
app.use(Session);
```

```
const RedisStore = connectRedis(session);
const redisClient = new Redis({ port: 6379, host: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "localhost" : "redis-server" });
const appSession: Express = express();
appSession.use(
    session({
        store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient }),
        secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET || "secret",
        name: "sid",
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        cookie: {
            secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? true : "auto",
            httpOnly: true,
            maxAge: UTIL.asSeconds(Cache.DEAULT_EXPIRATION),
            sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "none" : "lax",
        },
    }),
);

export const Session = appSession;
```

my api is just 'username' and 'password' - nothing special
it sets a 'sid' cookie and sets users in my session like I wrote above - nothing fancy...

Comment: P.S - when console logging the req.session.user right after setting it - it's there - it somehow gets deleted right after that.. I'm really lost because accessing the same endpoint through postman works like a charm...

Answer (score 0):

frontend:

```
const axios = Axios.create({ withCredentials: true });
```

and

on the backend

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: "http://localhost:8000" }));
```

hope this helps someone someday